# Safely and Quickly Trim a Byte Array of Audio in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, android, audio, byte

I'm trying to take a raw byte array of audio and trim it.

The user selects a start and end value using a range slider.

```
// args are doubles from 0.0 - 1.0
// audio is uncompressed, 16-bit, 44,100hz, MONO
public static byte[] trimBytes(byte[] fullLength, double from, double to) {

    int startingByteIndex = (int) ((double) fullLength.length * from);

    // samples/frames are two bytes long, so...
    // we make sure we don't include half a sample (corrupt audio)
    if (startingByteIndex %2 != 0) {
        startingByteIndex ++; // use plus, because minus could overflow
    }

    int endingByteIndex = (int) ((double) fullLength.length * to);
    int finalByteArrayLength = endingByteIndex - startingByteIndex;

    // make sure we don't include half a sample (corrupt audio)
    if (finalByteArrayLength %2 != 0) {
        finalByteArrayLength --; // use minus because plus could overflow
    }

    byte[] result = new byte[finalByteArrayLength];

    for (int i=0; i<finalByteArrayLength; i++) {
        int indexToCopy = startingByteIndex + i;
        result[i] = fullLength[indexToCopy];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Is this going to crash for any reason or is there a better way to do this?

Note: I cannot use Java.nio.

Comment: the android tag seems a bit confusing - i do not see any android specific code...

Answer (score 1):

> 0.0 - 1.0, Is this going to crash for any reason?

As you don't check, there's an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` that could be turned into an `IllegalArgumentException`.

> is there a better way to do this?

- Avoid copying altogether:
  Use [java.nio.ByteBuffer.slice()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#slice())
- Don't open code what the JRE provides:
  Use [java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(byte[] original, int from, int to)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(byte%5B%5D,int,int))

  ```
  final double halfLength = fullLength.length / 2.0;
  Arrays.copyOfRange(fullLength,
      (int)Math.ceil(halfLength * from) * 2,
      (int)Math.floor(halfLength * to) * 2);
  ```
- Don't write, never commit/publish uncommented/undocumented code, minimal:

  ```
  /** Returns a new Byte[] containing samples from fullLength
  *  starting at from (rounded up), ending at to (rounded down). */
  ```

Comment: Thanks!  Unfortunately I can't use java.nio due to min Android API requirement of 23.  But I will use the remainder of your advice.